# How to set docker to always use specific host IP or interface

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have linux machine, with docker installed, that works also as NAT router. It has multiple interfaces and I need docker to communicate by default with only one of them. After hours of trying custom networks, the best solution I found is to set the interface IP when specifying port mappings:

```
docker run -p 192.168.0.1:80:80 -d nginx
```

Where `192.168.0.1` is my interface IP. Is it possible to set docker to use that IP (interface) every time? E.g. when I download someone's docker-compose.yml and use it without changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the "ip" option to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```
{
    [...]
    "ip":"192.168.0.1"
}
```

After restarting the service, ports will be exposed on this interface instead of default `0.0.0.0` one.

afaik, the daemon.json file can accept any options as defined on dockerd itself: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/

Comment: hmmm after few more testing I am disappointed, It works only with docker run, but not with docker-compose

Comment: Yes, it seems that docker-compose create a default network instead of using default bridge which then bypass this daemon.json setting. Sadly it seems that the only available option is to make change to the compose file to use the default bridge or another external network defined with ```docker network create -o "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4"="192.168.0.1" local_network```. At this point I can only this of some firewall settings to avoid compose file modification at all.

Comment: I have iptables default DROP policy, but when docker image starts listening on 0.0.0.0, it also creates iptables rule to ACCEPT on all interfaces the image mapped ports. Thanks for the hint with the docker network, it is possible to define the newtwork with this settings using docker-compose.yml?
I am thinking if it is bug, that docker-compose is ignoring the daemon.json, maybe I should open bug report.